# Index out of range error, python 3.5. Only happens in 'while' loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception, python-3.5

Whilst coding a binary conversion program for my friend I kept getting an index out of range error when using the `X[N] = Y` command whereby `X` was a list, `N` was the index number is the list (represented by a variable called `Bit`) and `Y` was the value I was assigning to variable in index `N` in list `X`.

Well I should've just put the code and explained but basically it is saying the index is out of bounds whilst the code `Numbers[Bit] = 0` or `Number[Bit] = 1` is within a while loop, however it works everywhere else in the code. The variable `Bit` is equal to integer 7 and the list `Numbers` contains variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g` and `h` all separated meaning there are 0-7 indexes. And I tried with a `Bit` value of 0 and this did not work either. However the code worked fine as long as the `Numbers[Bit]` code sections were placed outside of the while loop. Any ideas?

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0

def loop():
    Bit = 7
    Numbers = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h];
    Num = 128
    Input = int(input("What Number do you want to convert?" ))

    while Input > 0:
        if Input > Num:
            Input = Input - Num
            Numbers[Bit] = 1
        else:
            Numbers[Bit] = 0

        Bit = Bit - 1
        Num = Num/2
    Numbers = str(Numbers)
    print (Numbers)

loop()
```

Comment: It was initially set to 7.

Comment: `Num/2` is not using integer division, it is using true division. You'll end up with fractions, not 0. That's not the whole problem, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing with `Input > Num`, which should be `Input >= Num`.

To get the bits in the correct order, you can use:

```
def loop():
    number = int(input("What Number do you want to convert?" ))
    bits = [(number>>b) & 1 for b in range(7,-1,-1)]
    print(bits)
```

Comment: `Num` becomes a fraction as well.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem although I realised the list is the wrong way round for binary but great help.